# how to check the previous buttons are selected when we are selecting last button in ios

Tags: ios

I have 5 buttons, when i select 4th button without selecting 1st,2nd,3rd buttons i need to show alert. how to check these condition.where iam using this condition is to give ratings.
can anyone explain the solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you please copy/paste portions of the code that you are trying to troubleshoot? We cannot help you with so little information.

Comment: So when you want to give a rating of 4 you need to click all 4 buttons? Not just the 4th? Just keep a counter that you check and increment each click on one of the 5 buttons. If I understand this right it's not very userfriendly.

Comment: @martijnn2008: agreed! this is not friendly while user have to touch one by one to give a rate.

Comment: -(IBAction)starState:(UIButton *)sender
{
    TYLTLogs(@"tag = %d",sender.tag);

    BOOL validated = YES;
    for (int i = 1; i < sender.tag; i++)
    {
        TYLTLogs(@"%d",i);
        if (!((UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:i]).isSelected)
            validated = NO;
        break;
    }
    
    
    if (!validated) {
    } else {
        sender.selected  = !sender.selected;
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can add Tag to your buttons: from 1 to 5 for example.

Then, in your function click on a button

```
-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender
{
    BOOL validated = YES;
    for (int i = 1; i < sender.tag; i++)
    {
        if (!((UIButton*)[currentView viewWithTag:i]).isSelected)
            validated = NO;
        break;
    }

    //show alert or not
    if (!validated)
        showAlert();
    else {
        //it's OK. Do your job 
    }
}
```

Comment: it's the superview of your buttons, where you've placed buttons in.

Comment: first I select all buttons except 1st button for this it is working fine.after that i select 1st button it is selected then i select 3rd,4th,5th buttons without selecting 2nd button all are selecting.

Comment: my code is  -(IBAction)starState:(UIButton *)sender
{
    BOOL validated = YES;
    for (int i = 1; i < sender.tag; i++)
    {
        if (!((UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:i]).isSelected)
            validated = NO;
        break;
    }
    
    if (validated) {
        sender.selected  = !sender.selected;
    }
}

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question in these comments. Can you explain? However, as another suggestion, if you develop a star rating, it's more friendly if application can auto-select the left-side star.

Comment: i need to give rating by selecting buttons and the order for this selecting is one by one continously.if i select 1st button it must be selected then if select 3rd button it should not why because at middle 2nd button is not selected na. so what is my concern is i need to select those buttons in order.